# Python Script as window service need to start on boot

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-services, daemon

I want to make my python script run in the background as well as it needs to start on boot.

- i'm using windows7 system
- python 3.6

I referred [this](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python)  link to make python script as window service. But when i start window service, its showing error:

```
The service is not responding to the control function.
```

- I have used SYSTEMD in linux to daemonize python script and also to manage processes. Is there any alternative for systemd ? 
  in windows so that I can go for that.
- **Python script which i want to run is :**

My python script:

```
import schedule
import time
import datetime
#datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")

def job():
    print("Scheduling is Working...")
    createfile()

def createfile():
    company = "HELLO USER"
    with open('company.txt', 'w+') as f:
            f.write(str(company))
            print("File Created on:",time.ctime(time.time()))
            f.close()
    return True
# schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
# schedule.every().hour.do(job)

#schedule.every().day.at("11.40").do(job)
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job)

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have daemons. The closest it comes is a Windows service. Windows services aren't hard to write and there is full support for in in Python Extensions for Windows. See https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/python/Python%20Programming%20on%20Win32_%20Help%20for%20Windows%20Programmers%20%5BHammond%20%26%20Robinson%202000-02-03%5D.pdf.

Comment: well, Any idea why i got error : The service is not responding to the control function.  when i run service @BoarGules

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you present that talks to the Windows service controller. Typically a Windows service has one thread that talks to the Windows service controller and another that actually does the work. I've referred you to the best reference. I can't compress an entire chapter of that book into a reply on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Task Scheduler to run the script on startup.

https://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/scheduling-a-python-script-to-run-upon-boot-at-a-predefined-time